# Are there continuous functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that f has no directional derivatives?

Tags: derivatives

[Can the non-differentiability of a function $f:R^n \to R$ always be proved by using directional derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861031/can-the-non-differentiability-of-a-function-frn-to-r-always-be-proved-by-us/2861084#2861084) leads to the question whether there is some (continuous) function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and all $(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$  the following limit $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f((x_0,y_0)+t(\alpha,\beta))-f((x_0,y_0))}{t}$$ does *not* exist.

Comment: How about $W_\alpha \otimes W_\alpha,$ where $W_\alpha$ is [the Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)?

Comment: Instead of $f(x) + f(y)$, how about $f(xy)$?